# How do I play a list of video IDs in an embedded YouTube player?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, youtube, playlist

I recently found this [jQuery YouTube TubePlayer Plugin](http://tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin) which lets you control the player, loading and playing videos.

It lets you define an '[onPlayerEnded](http://tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin#tubeplayer_tutorial_3)' action (allowing me to play the next video by its ID), but this parameter cannot be changed after it has been set and the player has been intialised, I think. As such, my 'playlist' is limited to two videos: the initial video and the one which is played after the initial video ends.

Am I wrong and is there a way to get this working using the plugin after all, or should I try a different approach?

The YouTube API, for example, offers a [loadPlaylist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#loadPlaylist) function which accepts an array of video IDs, but I wouldn't know where to start when trying to use this API directly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The embeddable player takes a playlist parameter in the form of an array:

```
<div id="ytapiplayer">
      You will need Flash 8 or better to view this content.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
          var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
          var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };

          playlistids = new Array('_T8dw1nK7b0','aF4i2XXFqL0','a_lsWeGq-HM')

          swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/OQSNhk5ICTI&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3&playlist=" + playlistids, "ytapiplayer", "425", "365", "8", null, null, params, atts);

          function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
            ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
          }
</script>
```

This requires [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to be included.

Answer (score 1):

You can use loadVideoById on ytplayer

```
 if (ytplayer) {
        ytplayer.loadVideoById(id, 0, "default");//Replace id with the video id.
    }
```

Comment: 'on ytplayer'? Would that be YouTube's own or is it another plugin? If you could link me to any kind of documentation about this that'd be sweet. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: ytplayer is the name of the ytplayer object as in various examples in the documentation.